# Autoinstall libpam-ldap

Tags: linux, bash, shell, apt

I'm trying to autoinstall libpam-ldap with a script, but its not working properly. As now I have

```
apt-get install libpam-ldap -y
```

That's alright, but then it goes into another window after answering Y to a continue question, and inside there I have to fill out IPs and other stuff. How can I skip through this? How can I echo "Enter" so I can skip through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq libpam-ldap
```

However using -qq is discouraged (check man apt-get) so try with '-q'

Anyways important for you is `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`